# Is it possible to create a new object using Lambda instead of an anonymous class?

Tags: java, lambda, inner-classes, anonymous

I have this interface:

```
public interface Result
{
    public Path path();
    public int line();
}
```

I want to create an arraylist of results, and it works fine doing this:

```
list.add(new Result{
    @Override
    path(){
        return "some string";
    }
    @Override
    line(){
        return 1; // some integer
    }

});
```

I am new to lambda expressions, and I have tried to implement this using a lambda instead, but I cannot seem to get the syntax right. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use lambda expressions to implement interfaces having a single abstract method (i.e. functional interfaces).

Since your `Result` interface has two methods, it can't be implemented with a lambda expression.

Comment: That's what i thought, but I was still confused about it. Thanks. Is an anonymous innerclass the best way to build this list?

Comment: @yeahboy You can also use regular classes that implement `Result`. I guess the best way is a matter of opinion, and would depend on your specific use case.

Comment: I see. Thanks, that answered my questions :)